# Ionic native google maps error adding polyline

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I've had great success with Native Google maps in Ionic 3 except for one issue (of course it's a blocker). I am able to add a polyline and marker to my map, but the promise never returns the handle for these objects. Instead I get these errors:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot set property 'polyline_695608509981' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set property 'polyline_695608509981' of undefined
    at Map.<anonymous> (vendor.js:82267)
    at Map.<anonymous> (Map.js:1206)
    at commandQueueExecutor.js:63
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3) TypeError: Cannot set property 'polyline_695608509981' of undefined
    at Map.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:82267:57)
    at Map.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Map.js:1206:16)
    at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/commandQueueExecutor.js:63:21
    at t.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
    at r.run (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
    at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
    at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
    at r.runTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
    at o (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:7894)
n.onUnhandledError @ polyfills.js:3
r @ polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
n.microtaskDrainDone @ polyfills.js:3
o @ polyfills.js:3
Promise.then (async)
r @ polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.js:3
f @ polyfills.js:3
c @ polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
t @ polyfills.js:3
t.then @ polyfills.js:3
nextTick @ Common.js:6
commandQueue.push.args @ commandQueueExecutor.js:62
callbackFromNative @ cordova.js:291
(anonymous) @ VM815:1
polyfills.js:3 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot set property 'marker_1292454192683' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set property 'marker_1292454192683' of undefined
    at Map.<anonymous> (vendor.js:82081)
    at Map.<anonymous> (Map.js:1293)
    at commandQueueExecutor.js:63
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3) TypeError: Cannot set property 'marker_1292454192683' of undefined
    at Map.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:82081:57)
    at Map.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Map.js:1293:16)
    at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/commandQueueExecutor.js:63:21
    at t.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
    at r.run (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
    at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
    at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
    at r.runTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
    at o (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:7894)
```

My first thought is that I'm using the map at the wrong point in the Ionic lifecycle. I am calling the following function from ionViewDidLoad() which I believe is the correct approach. The function is shown below:

loadMap() {

```
let options: PolylineOptions = {
    points: this.coords,
    color: '#AA00FF',
    width: 10,
    geodesic: true,
    zoom: true,
    strokeOpacity: 1.0
};

const VICTORIA_BC = {"lat": 48.4238642, "lng": -123.36846639};

this.map = new GoogleMap('map_canvas', {
    'controls': {
        'compass': true,
        'myLocationButton': true,
        'indoorPicker': true,
     },
     'gestures': {
          'scroll': true,
          'tilt': true,
          'rotate': true,
          'zoom': true
      },
      'camera': {
          target: VICTORIA_BC,
          zoom: 18,
          tilt: 30
      }
  });

  let marker = this.map.addMarker({
      title: 'TItle',
      icon: 'blue',
      animation: 'DROP',
      position: {
          lat: 48.4238642,
          lng: -123.36846639
      }
  })
  .then((marker) => {
      marker.showInfoWindow();
  })
  .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
  });

  this.map.addPolyline(options)
  .then((result) => {
        console.log("Added polyline" + JSON.stringify(result));
        this.line = result;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    }); 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Stuart

Comment: Looks like this error was caused by mixing code from different approaches to creating maps. I was using `this.map = new GoogleMap('map_canvas', mapOptions)`. The issue was fixed by entering `this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions)`.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vScoho1ensbR4qCI9AIuQN55BZVvK73pAjI7sumDvW3CrxxHnrmpXWUjx2-8CpFibqU1EjLKCRhuthJ/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000&slide=id.p